# GMap Image Cutter. Why Add Marker to Map with Infinite Number?

Tags: google-maps, marker

I use GMap Image Cutter to prepare a custom Map. It works.

However when I try to add a Marker on the Map:

```
//Add marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map:map,
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
  title: "My Marker"
});
```

Infinite number of markers are lying along in x=0 axis.The distance between two markers is the width of the map.

I play around for the whole day but still cannot get the solution.

How can I add only a single marker?

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Hi Pugazh, Thanks for your great help. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a example to get started. Adjust the latitude and longitude as per your need.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #map {
      width: 500px;
      height: 400px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    function initMap() {
      var myLatLng = {
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0
      };
      var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
      var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: {
          lat: 44.540,
          lng: -78.546
        },
        zoom: 1
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Pugazh, Thanks for your great help. Problem solved.

Comment: @Alex :  Happy to help!